# HTTP Get to an API returns protocol violation error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have an ASP.Net MVC Web API endpoint that connects to another API endpoint (same domain).
When the Javascript client is using HTTP Get to connect to this MVC Web API, I get a protocol violation (via Fiddler):
Content-Length response header MUST NOT be present when Transfer-Encoding is used (RFC2616 Section 4.4)

Here's the Javascript code:

```
    $http.get('search?collectionSet=' + collectionSet +
        '&query=google' +
        '&type=COMPANYFILINGS')
        .success(function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }).error(function() {
            deferred.reject();
        });
```

The other endpoint is using chunked for content-encoding.
When I switched the Javascript to use POST, it works without error.
The Javascript client is using AngularJS $http.get.
Any parameters in the GET that I need to set to stop this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Interested to see how many people can debug code without even seeing it.

Comment: Updated it. Good point.